# woocommerce virtual product customisation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customise the checkout process of a virtual product so that woocommerce can be used to take bookings for a restaurant. The idea is to remove all references that you are paying for a product and just make it look like a booking system (which will be free). The

```
if( woo_cart_has_virtual_product() == true )
```

statement looks promising to modify the checkout process. Is this possible?

Comment: May be a better fit for [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: to me it seems like making simple thinks complicated. What extra outcome will be from use of woocomerce for this purpose? Are you planning to set all possible bookings as a product to sell? Why not write a simple form with access to a database table with free tables?

Comment: Woocommerce is already being used and the staff are familiar with it. Keeping all sales and booking requests in the same area would be beneficial